# Solving exponential system

Tags: algebraic-equations

How can i solve the following system?

$
  \begin{cases}
    x^y = 16  \\
    \frac{x}{y}=2\\
  \end{cases}$

I tried everything, nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried guessing the answer, using familiar numbers? This unfortunately is not the right site for your question; MathOverflow is actually for mathematics professionals and their PhD students to discuss matters connected with their research.